# Failed 2010 SP1 Upgrade

Tags: 2010, upgrade, cumulative-update

Anyone have an idea?  I am trying to upgrade on Win7 Development box

```
06/30/2011 11:11:20  8  ERR            Task upgrade has failed with a PostSetupConfigurationTaskException An exception of type Microsoft.SharePoint.PostSetupConfiguration.PostSetupConfigurationTaskException was thrown.  Additional exception information: The upgrade command is invalid or a failure has been encountered.
Failed to upgrade SharePoint Products.
06/30/2011 11:11:20  8  INF            Entering function Common.BuildExceptionInformation
06/30/2011 11:11:20  8  INF              Entering function Common.BuildExceptionMessage
06/30/2011 11:11:20  8  INF                Entering function StringResourceManager.GetResourceString
06/30/2011 11:11:20  8  INF                  Resource id to be retrieved is ExceptionInfo for language English (United States)
06/30/2011 11:11:20  8  INF                  Resource retrieved id ExceptionInfo is An exception of type {0} was thrown.  Additional exception information: {1}
06/30/2011 11:11:20  8  INF                Leaving function StringResourceManager.GetResourceString
06/30/2011 11:11:20  8  INF              Leaving function Common.BuildExceptionMessage
06/30/2011 11:11:20  8  INF            Leaving function Common.BuildExceptionInformation
06/30/2011 11:11:20  8  ERR            An exception of type Microsoft.SharePoint.PostSetupConfiguration.PostSetupConfigurationTaskException was thrown.  Additional exception information: The upgrade command is invalid or a failure has been encountered.
Failed to upgrade SharePoint Products.
Microsoft.SharePoint.PostSetupConfiguration.PostSetupConfigurationTaskException: Exception of type 'Microsoft.SharePoint.PostSetupConfiguration.PostSetupConfigurationTaskException' was thrown.
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.PostSetupConfiguration.UpgradeTask.Run()
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.PostSetupConfiguration.TaskThread.ExecuteTask()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We had the same issue...

try running this:

```
psconfig -cmd upgrade -inplace b2b -force
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to analyze the log file starting with 'Upgrade' on the [ERROR] text. Does these messages make sense to you (your environment)?

Comment: @Chillyago You'll most likely find this file at `C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\14\LOGS` and it will be called something like `Upgrade-20110630-130832-446-error.log`.

Comment: The above snippet is from the upgrade log.

Comment: As seen from the layout of the part of the log, this is not from the file starting with 'Upgrade...' logfile, but from the logfile starting with 'PSCDiagnostics...' (the link from the Configuration failed window of the SharePoint Products Configuration Wizard). Can you please check for the 'Upgrade..' log.

Answer (score 1):

Our experience here is that trying to do SharePoint 2010 on Win7, while technically possible is more or less a minefield where things like this pop up all the time.  Rather than spend even more time troubleshooting the Win7 option we ended up just putting SharePoint 2010 on virtual machines running Windows Server and have had excellent results with that.

I realize that this doesn't really help you solve your problem now but it might be something to consider in the future.

Comment: sad but probably true